# Connecting to MongoDB with requests library

Tags: python, mongodb, python-requests

I have a situation where I need to pass some data to MongoDB but am limited in the libraries I can access and so can only use requests.  This is what I have so far, but it's always throwing a 'No connection adapters were found' error.  I've confirmed that I have manual access to the server.  I've also tried this both with and withouht setting the connection first, but get the same error either way.

```
data = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Numbers'])

# Create a connection to the MongoDB database
connection = requests.Session()
# Post the document to the MongoDB database
response = connection.post(r'mongodb+srv://username:password@name.aaaa.mongodb.net/db_name/collection_name', json=df.to_dict())
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to [Atlas Data API](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/data-api/)? In that case your URL is wrong, it should start with `https`. If this is a self hosted DB, you'll need a  [database driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/python/) to connect to the database and interact with it, or set up your own separate API.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.  We aren't able to use the Atlas Data API for this, and so since we aren't able to use PyMongo, I suppose a custom API is the only way to go.